# How do I install a node module in a Cypress Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cypress

In the path ~/cypress-dockerfile I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/base:10
RUN npm install --save-dev cypress
WORKDIR /node_modules
RUN npm install sqlite3
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify
RUN $(npm bin)/cypress run
```

I then run `docker build .` but it stops with the following:

```
Step 4/6 : RUN npm install sqlite3
 ---> Running in 13de6b7a4fcf
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

> sqlite3@5.0.0 install /node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: not found
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
npm WARN !invalid#1 No description
npm WARN !invalid#1 No repository field.
npm WARN !invalid#1 No README data
npm WARN !invalid#1 No license field.

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-08-07T13_28_54_118Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install sqlite3' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I think that I may be in the wrong directory but I am not sure, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to install if *globally* in the container you need the `-g` flag. If you want to install it for a package you'll need to either copy the package definition in or create a new one (`npm init -y` to skip the interactive part). Although why you'd then to try to install another package in the `node_modules/` directory, which also won't be package, is beyond me.

Comment: Are you sure the package.json is not missing? Create and copy that file,   `ENOENT: **no such file or directory**, open **'/package.json'**`

Comment: Seems like you're running the command npm install sqlite3 inside node_modules directory.